# Move files to folders based on its name

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I have a file with a lot of tutorial links, so I wanted to create a script that reads the file name and for instance, if the file has in its name the word "vba" or "excel" it would create the folder Excel and send to it. The same would happen with files containing the word "python".

Here is what I have in the folder, all files are links to youtube tutorials or websites:
[image]

I'm having the following error when trying to do it:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "c:\Users\RMBORGE\Desktop\PythonLib\organize.py", line 8, in <module>
>         print(os.path.splitext(f))
>       File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
>     UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 21-22: character maps to <undefined>
```

Please see my code below:

```
import os
import shutil

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\RMBORGE\Desktop\Useful stuff")
path = r"C:\Users\RMBORGE\Desktop\Useful stuff\Excel"

for f in os.listdir():
    print(os.path.splitext(f))
    if "vba" in f:
       shutil.move(os.chdir,path)
```

Comment: i faced this problem before. try running your code without printing file names. windows terminal have some problem with unicode when you use print.

Comment: It's failing at the print. You should check which file it fails at by printing f, from your image it's the unicode characters.

Comment: I solved my problem by running this two lines of commands on terminal before running the py file. I was having problem with some special characters on arabic language.  `chcp 65001` and `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

Comment: @Nesi Tried to remove the print statement, the code runs without error, but nothing happened at all. All files remained in the main folder. Tried to run the commands on terminal but nothing happened as well.